# Selenium crashes when I'm trying to parse the next page (and seven after it) on a website. Any way to tackle this?

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors, webdriverwait, js-scrollintoview

I want to parse an IMDb film rating located [here](https://www.imdb.com/list/ls000004717/) on around 8 pages. In order to do that I'm using Selenium, and I'm having trouble with clicks, proceeding algorithm to next page. In the end I need 1000 titles when I'll continue using BeautifulSoup. Code below isn't working, I need to use button 'NEXT' with this HTML:

```
<a class="flat-button lister-page-next next-page" href="/list/ls000004717/?page=2">
            Next
        </a>
```

This is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver as wb
browser = wb.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.imdb.com/list/ls000004717/')
field = browser.find_element_by_name("flat-button lister-page-next next-page").click()
```

Error is the following:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".flat-button lister-page-next next-page"}
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.108)
```

I suppose I lack knowledge of syntax needed, or maybe I mixed it up a little. I tried searching on SO, though every example is pretty unique and I don't possess the knowledge to extrapolate these cases fully. Any way Selenium can handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways that could work:
1. Use a selector for the next button and loop until the end:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.imdb.com/list/ls000004717/')
selector = 'a[class*="next-page"]'

num_pages = 10
for page in range(pages):

    # Wait for the element to load
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector)))
    # ... Do rating parsing here

    browser.find_element_by_css_selector(selector).click()
```

Instead of clicking on the element, the other option could be to navigate to the next page using `broswer.get('...')`:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec

# Set up browser as before and navigate to the page
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.imdb.com/list/ls000004717/')
selector = 'a[class*="next-page"]'
base_url = 'https://www.imdb.com/list/ls000004717/'
page_extension = '?page='

# Already at page = 1, so only needs to loop 9 times
for page in range(2, pages + 1):
    # Wait for the page to load
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector)))
    # ... Do rating parsing here

    next_page = base_url + page_extension + str(page)
    browser.get(next_page)
```

As a note: `field = browser.find_element_by_name("...").click()` will *not* assign `field` to a webelement, as the `click()` method has no return value.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's fully working. Though after '# ... Do rating parsing here', which you providently put in advance, my Soup-code doesn't seem to be working well: it parses only the last page (2010's), while all the previous remain unparsed. This is the code:

`for page in range(2, 11):
    # Wait for the page to load
    WebDriverWait(browser, 11).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector)))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source)

    next_page = base_url + page_extension + str(page)
    browser.get(next_page)`

Comment: That's an extension of the question, of course, though I suspect that I may lack some not very complex 'append' here. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using an XPath to query on the `Next` text inside the button. You should also probably invoke `WebDriverWait` since you are navigating across multiple pages, then scroll into view since this is at the bottom of the page:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from time import sleep


browser = wb.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.imdb.com/list/ls000004717/')

# keep clicking next until we reach the end
for i in range(0,9):

    # wait up to 10s before locating next button
    try:    
        next_button = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class, 'page') and contains(text(), 'Next')]")))

        # scroll down to button using Javascript
        browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", next_button)

        # click the button
    #    next_button.click() this throws exception -- replace with JS click
        browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_button)

        # I never recommend using sleep like this, but WebDriverWait is not waiting on next button to fully load, so it goes stale.
        sleep(5)

    # case: next button no longer exists, we have reached the end
    except TimeoutException:
        break
```

I also wrapped everything in a `try` / `except TimeoutException` block to handle the case where we have reached the end of pages, and `Next` button no longer exists, thus breaking out of the loop. This worked on multiple pages for me.

I also had to add an explicit `sleep(5)` because even after invoking `WebDriverWait` on `element_to_be_clickable`, `next_button` was still throwing `StaleElementReferenceException`. It seems like `WebDriverWait` was finishing before page was fully loaded, causing the status of `next_button` to change after it had been located. Normally adding `sleep(5)` is bad practice, but there did not seem to be another workaround here. If anyone else has a suggestion on this, feel free to comment / edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer. Unfortunately, the algorithm stops at the 2nd page with this:

`ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a class="flat-button lister-page-next next-page" href="/list/ls000004717/?page=2">...</a> is not clickable at point (545, 16). Other element would receive the click: <div class="row text-center lister-working hidden" style="display: block;"></div> (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.108)`

Though your method is looking quite pleasing aesthetically, with the screen scrolling down to 'next' button automatically.

Comment: @SlavaGrivachev Updated my answer to use a different click strategy. I also added an explicit `sleep(5)`, because `WebDriverWait` was not waiting on `Next` button to fully load. I ran this script locally with success.

Comment: Thanks. It is fully working, but for some reasons stops at page 7 around title 768. I don't know the reason yet, will be researching on this.

Comment: @SlavaGrivachev I did notice an interesting issue around page 7. The XPath returns a link to the movie "Next of Kin" (because it contains the string 'Next') and clicks on that instead of the next button. I have updated my code with a new XPath for `next_button` that successfully clicks through every page, including page 7. The loop was also never quitting because the 'Next' button does not disappear even on page 10. This has been fixed as well, by changing `while True` to `for i in range(0,9)`.

Comment: Wow, that's truly fascinating. We used the Russian version of IMDb here (language is chosen automatically), and we didn't manage to find out the reason why. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try a partial css selector.

`browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a[class*='next-page']").click()`

Comment: Thanks, for the first time it works, but the page turns only once (from 1-100 to 101-200) – and I want it to go until the very end (901-1000). Any way I can achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

To click on the element with text as **NEXT** till the *`901 - 1,000 of 1,000`* page you have to:

- `scrollIntoView()` the element once the `visibility_of_element_located()` is achieved.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()`
- You can use the following solution:

  - Code Block:

    ```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get('https://www.imdb.com/list/ls000004717/')
    driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.pagination-range"))))
    while True:
        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.row.text-center.lister-working.hidden")))
            driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.pagination-range"))))
            WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.flat-button.lister-page-next.next-page"))).click()
            print("Clicked on NEXT button")
        except TimeoutException as e:
            print("No more NEXT button")
            break
    driver.quit()
    ```
  - Console Output:

    ```
    Clicked on NEXT button
    Clicked on NEXT button
    Clicked on NEXT button
    Clicked on NEXT button
    Clicked on NEXT button
    Clicked on NEXT button
    Clicked on NEXT button
    Clicked on NEXT button
    Clicked on NEXT button
    No more NEXT button
    ```